# Permanganate oxidation of side chains in Benzene Derivatives

Tags: aromatic-compounds

What is the exact mechanism of permanganate oxidation of side chain derivatives of benzene? Is it same for all functional groups? I want to know that in any situation I mean when side chain has only one benzylic hydrogen gives the carboxylic acid. Why does it occur?

Comment: I have changed the question. @Mithoron I wanted to know why exactly this is occurring. Even with one benzylic hydrogen, the product is same. Is there any definitive answer to my question?

Comment: Answer to original describes mechanism in general way. And does answer this.

Comment: But I want more exact mechanism for my question.